# how to create images interactive from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, pyqt, dockerfile

i want to create an image about PyQt5 from Dockerfile .
the following is part code in Dockerfile.

```
RUN cd PyQt-gpl-5.5.1 &&\ 
        python3  configure.py
```

when the code executes,it will ask me **"Do you accept the terms of the license?"**,but i can't type any word.

And i don't want to use the command 'commit'.
so how to create an image **interactive** from Dockerfile?

Comment: Have a look at tools like expect and yes. You might be able to just do "yes | python3 configure.py"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a shell pipe does not work, you can fall back to [an expect script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

You can see one used in [`visity/docker-build-android`](https://github.com/visity/docker-build-android) which install expect in [its Dockerfile](https://github.com/visity/docker-build-android/blob/d033915b36f5b85412eeddf8c50174661c272dcc/Dockerfile#L11)

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes expect ...
```

A [`tools/android-accept-licenses.sh`](https://github.com/visity/docker-build-android/blob/d033915b36f5b85412eeddf8c50174661c272dcc/tools/android-accept-licenses.sh) allows the docker build tp use android *after* accepting the license first:

```
expect {
  "Do you accept the license '*'*" {
        exp_send "y\r"
        exp_continue
  }
  eof
}
```

It is used [by the Dockerfile](https://github.com/visity/docker-build-android/blob/d033915b36f5b85412eeddf8c50174661c272dcc/Dockerfile#L20-L23):

```
COPY tools /opt/tools
ENV PATH ${PATH}:/opt/tools
RUN ["/opt/tools/android-accept-licenses.sh", "android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter platform-tools,tools,build-tools-22.0.1,android-22,addon-google_apis_x86-google-22,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22"]
```

Here, `android-accept-licenses.sh` is part of the host `/opt/tools` which is COPY'ed to the image, and then used in a `RUN` directive.

Comment: can you improve your answer to explaing step by step how to use the `,sh` file please? I mean COPY/ADD etc,...